# ffmpeg mass transcode videos in directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, ffmpeg

I have loads of videos named different things and different extensions (some mp4 some wmv etc).

I would like to run the command below but on every video in a specific directory and then save that in another directory, no overwrites of original files.

Some videos maybe duplicates, if that happens it should pause the script. For example there maybe `video1.mp4` & `video1.avi` both can't be video1.mp4  in `/home/videos/processed`so the script should pause.

```
ffmpeg -i '/home/videos/unprocessed/vidabc.mp4' -f mp4 -vcodec libx264 -preset fast -profile:v main -acodec aac -movflags +faststart '/home/videos/processed/vidabc.mp4'
ffmpeg -i '/home/videos/unprocessed/vidxyz.mp4' -f mp4 -vcodec libx264 -preset fast -profile:v main -acodec aac -movflags +faststart '/home/videos/processed/vidxyz.mp4'
```

Comment: To clarify, it sounds like you have 2 questions: 1, how to run the command on all files in a directory, and 2, how to script a pause (maybe a confirm dialog?) in the event of a duplicate filename. Is that correct?

Comment: ffmpeg by default asks to replace so I think it may work fine without. Just wanted to make that clear if it would cause any problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can process every file in a directory using the `find` command with the `-execdir` flag.

Example:

```
find /home/videos/unprocessed -type f \
   -execdir ffmpeg -i '{}' -f mp4 -vcodec libx264 -preset fast \
   -profile:v main -acodec aac -movflags +faststart '/home/videos/processed/{}.mp4' \;
```

`-type f` indicates that you want to find only files, not directories.

After the `-execdir` flag, `'{}'` is replaced with the path of the file, e.g. `./vidabc.mp4`.

At the end of the `-execdir` command, include a `\;` to terminate the command.

Note that in this example, your resulting filenames might look like:

- `/home/videos/processed/vidabc.mp4.mp4`
- `/home/videos/processed/vidxyz.avi.mp4`
- `/home/videos/processed/vidxyz.mp4.mp4`

If that is a problem, there are ways to address that. See [Command “find” -exec replacing string](https://superuser.com/questions/854740/command-find-exec-replacing-string) for a similar example.

Comment: **find: missing argument to `-execdir'
Try 'find --help' for more information.** when running **find /home/vids/todo/new -type f \
   -execdir ffmpeg -i '{}' -f mp4 -vcodec libx264 -preset fast \
   -profile:v main -acodec aac -movflags +faststart '/home/vids/todo/newencoded/{}.mp4'**

Comment: I was missing the terminator to the command specified in -execdir. I've edited the post and added it. See the man page for find, particularly the sections for -exec and -execdir, for details.